# Get frame of UIImageview's image covered - iOS

Tags: iphone, ipad, object, uiimage, core-graphics

I have one image which has some transparent area and i wants to ignore that area.

And get that covered frame with maximum possibility..

here i have upload one image so you get idea what i am asking.

[image]

i have used some logic and function to evaluate this frame but still i could not the exact frame.

And i want dynamic code so i can change this kind of image.

Here i have attached sample code which i have used.

```
-(CGRect)getImageRect:(UIImage *)image{

    int x1,y1,x2,y2;
    BOOL flag=NO;
    CGFloat red,green,blue,alpha;

    UIColor *color=nil;

    // Get starting position y1
    flag=NO;
    for (int y=0; y<image.size.height; y++) {
        for (int x=0; x<image.size.width; x++) {
            // Get pixel color for
            color=[self getPixelColor:image withX:x withY:y];

            [color getRed:&red green:&green blue:&blue alpha:&alpha];

            if (red==0 && green==0 && blue==0 && alpha==0){
                continue;
            }else{
                y1=y;
                flag=YES;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (flag) {
            break;
        }
    }

    // Get starting position x1
    flag=NO;
    for (int x=0; x<image.size.width; x++) {

        for (int y=0; y<image.size.height; y++) {
            // Get pixel color for
            color=[self getPixelColor:image withX:x withY:y];

            [color getRed:&red green:&green blue:&blue alpha:&alpha];

            if (red==0 && green==0 && blue==0 && alpha==0) {
                continue;
            }else {
                x1=x;
                flag=YES;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (flag) {
            break;
        }
    }

    // Get last position y2
    flag=NO;
    for (int y=image.size.height; y>=0; y--) {

        for (int x=image.size.width; x>=0; x--) {
            // Get pixel color for
            color=[self getPixelColor:image withX:x withY:y];

            [color getRed:&red green:&green blue:&blue alpha:&alpha];

            if (red==0 && green==0 && blue==0 && alpha==0) {
                continue;
            }
            else {
                y2=y;
                flag=YES;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (flag) {
            break;
        }
    }

    // Get last position x2
    flag=NO;
    for (int x=image.size.width; x>=0; x--) {

        for (int y=image.size.height; y>=0; y--) {
            // Get pixel color for
            color=[self getPixelColor:image withX:x withY:y];

            [color getRed:&red green:&green blue:&blue alpha:&alpha];

            if (red==0 && green==0 && blue==0 && alpha==0) {
                continue;
            }
            else {
                x2=x;
                flag=YES;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (flag) {
            break;
        }
    }

    return CGRectMake(x1, y1, x2-x1, y2-y1);
}
- (UIColor *)getPixelColor:(UIImage *)image withX:(int)x withY:(int)y {

    CFDataRef pixelData = CGDataProviderCopyData(CGImageGetDataProvider(image.CGImage));
    const UInt8* data = CFDataGetBytePtr(pixelData);

    int pixelInfo = ((image.size.width  * y) + x ) * 4; // The image is png

    UInt8 red = data[pixelInfo];         // Get red info
    UInt8 green = data[(pixelInfo + 1)]; // Get red info
    UInt8 blue = data[pixelInfo + 2];    // Get red info
    UInt8 alpha = data[pixelInfo + 3];   // I need only this info for my maze game
    CFRelease(pixelData);

    UIColor* color = [UIColor colorWithRed:red/255.0f green:green/255.0f blue:blue/255.0f alpha:alpha/255.0f]; // The pixel color info

    return color;
}
```

please post your helpful comments and answer to short out this

/----------
Edited

i need frame which is covered by orange color. and i have draw orange color for only understand my question. its not required.

Regards,

Comment: u want whole image be covered with frame of orange color

Comment: yes i want only frame which is covered by orange color